# intel icpc compilation with -xhost option : AVX activated?

Tags: avx, avx2, icc

I am using icpc compiler to see the speed up of my code usually compiled with g++.

The processor on which I compile belongs to Intel's Sandy Bridge architecture, so I want to use AVX vectorization.

Someone told that the "-xhost" flag with icpc could allow me to benefit automatically from AVX vectorization : is this the case ?

If not, could you tell the flag(s) to put with icpc to activate AVX.

Last question: could I benefit from AVX2 too ? and if yes, how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To benefit from AVX2 you need a 4th generation Intel Coree(R) processor, built upon Haswell architecture.

Your CPU supports only AVX. You can instruct the compiler to use it as you mentioned by using "**-xHost**" compilation flag. This tells the compiler to use the highest SIMD like instructions available on your host machine. You can also use "-**mavx**" flag.

*Be aware although that if you generate code using AVX, you will be able to run it only on machines that have AVX (later than Sandy Bridge).*

To check if the compiler has generated AVX code, dump the assemblies and look for the YMM registers. Those are AVX specific.For more info look **[here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522846)**.

Cheers!